# Nginx not loading index

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am attempting to serve all static content on nginx and php files on my apache server.

server {
        listen   80;

```
    root /var/www/tb/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name  37.*;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php @forward;
            #limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
    }


    location @forward {

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://myip
    }
```

Unfortunately when I navigate to my website's url then I am shown the directory index instead of index.php(or a 403 if i disable autolisting.

If I append the url with http://myurl/index it works though. but http://myurl does not.

Comment: index.php exists ONLY on the remote server. Not on the nginx server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php @forward;
```

Will:

1. check whether the url is a file, and if it is serve it
2. check whether the url is a directory, and if it is serve the directory index (`index.php index.html index.htm`)
3. check whether the file `/var/www/tb/index.php` exists, and if it does use that
4. And finally, proxy the remote server

Steps 2 and 3 are not wanted, so simply remove them. In this way if the request maps exactly to a file it is served, and if not the request is handled by the `@forward` location block.

The complete config based on the question is therefore:

```
root /var/www/tb/;
server_name  37.*;

location / {
        try_files $uri @forward;
}

location @forward {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://myip
}
```

Note that there's no need to define the `index` directive since it's not going to be used.